# Excel \ OpenOffice Calc Dir function does not iterate thru files

Tags: excel, vba, openoffice-calc, dir

My VBA-Code only returns the first file of the the directory while it should return at least 3 files, does anyone have a clue whats going on here?

```
FolderName = Environ("UserProfile") + "\"
FilePath = FolderName & "Invoice." & Format(Date,"yyyy.mm.dd") & "-" & "*" & ".ods"

count = 1
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

While (FileName <> "" And count < 5)
    MsgBox "FileName = " + FileName
    count = count + 1
Wend
```

Comment: I cant accept answer for another 50 seconds... Rookie policy of StackoverFlow. PS: Do you know how to format a digit to 3-digits? For example 3 to 003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (note that I added `FileName = Dir` in the end of the `While` loop):

```
FolderName = Environ("UserProfile") + "\"
FilePath = FolderName & "Invoice." & Format(Date,"yyyy.mm.dd") & "-" & "*" & ".ods"

count = 1
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

While (FileName <> "" And count < 5)
    MsgBox "FileName = " + FileName
    count = count + 1
    FileName = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: Another quick question, do you know how to format a digit to 3-digits?
For example 3 to 003

Comment: Yes, I know. Just apply custom formating "000" to the cell, or use excel formula `=Text("A1","000")`

Comment: the same thing with VBA: `MsgBox Format(3, "000")`

Comment: If you got time for one last question how do you add a VBA-string to the excel-sheet

Comment: what do you mean by `add a VBA-string to the excel-sheet` ? this one: `Range("A1")="something"`?

Comment: Yes, I want to move the string to a Cell B7, but the string is in the macro or VBA

Comment: write `Range("B7")="something"` or if your string in some varaible: `Range("B7")=myVariable`

Comment: I get "basic runtime error sub procedure or function procedure not defined"

Comment: Have you use this string inside `Sub` statement? If no, sandwitch `Range("B7")="something"` with `Sub test()` and `End Sub`